# Read two items at a time in a foor-loop

Tags: php

I've got an array

```
$fruits = ["apple", "RED", "lychee", "RED", "mango", "GREEN", "papaya", "ORANGE"];
```

I need to access two items at a time. How can I do this using the for-loop?

```
for ($i=0;$i<$fruits.length/2;$i += 2){
   $items = '<img src="'.$fruits[$i].'"><img src="'.$weldy[$i+1].'">';
}
```

Expected output:

```
<img src="apple"><img src="RED">
<img src="lychee"><img src="RED">
<img src="mango"><img src="GREEN">
<img src="papaya"><img src="ORANGE">
```

Comment: why is your array 1 dimension?

Comment: Using such way to store data is not advised. You can use key & value of array to make your life a bit easier...

Comment: `foreach (array_chunk($fruits,2) as $i) 
       $items[] = '<img src="'.$i[0].'"><img src="'.$i[1].'">';`

Comment: @splash58: That's brilliant! :) Is there a way to identify the last set of items? I need to add a `<br><br>` after `<img src="papaya"><img src="ORANGE">` within the foreach loop?

Comment: put them just after foreach. why in?

Comment: `implode('<br><br>', $items);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = array_chunk($fruits, 2);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo '<img src="' . $item[0] . '"><img src="' . $item[1] . '">';
}
```

seems to work nicely. `array_chunk` will break the list up for you.

Comment: This works.  Is there a way to identify the last set of items? I need to add a `<br><br>` after `<img src="papaya"><img src="ORANGE">` within the foreach loop?

Comment: Why not just output `<br><br>` after the end of the loop? Or if you have `<br>` inside the loop between items, just add the second `<br>` once the loop has ended.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I wrote it incorrectly. I need to add the br tags at the end of each line except for the last one. So `<img src="apple"><img src="RED"> <br><br> <img src="lychee"><img src="RED"> <br><br> <img src="mango"><img src="GREEN"> <br><br> <img src="papaya"><img src="ORANGE">`

Comment: foreach ($items as $k => $item) {
  if ($k < count($items)-1) { echo '<br> <br>' }
  echo '<img src="' . $item[0] . '"><img src="' . $item[1] . '">';
 }

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0;$i<$fruits.length/2;$i += 2){
```

..is javascript notation.

Try:

```
for ($i=0;$i<(count($fruits)/2);$i += 2){
```